# PHP session and memcacheD

Tags: apache, memcached, php

Everybody knows there are two extensions for memcache on PHP:

- memcache
- memcached

You can use memcache the PHP extension as a session_handler for PHP like so :

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://serv01:11211,tcp://serv02:11211,tcp://serv03:11211"
```

Or you can use memcached like so:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "serv01:11211,serv02:11211,serv03:11211"
```

But how to set other parameters to memcached such as:

- Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION
- Memcached::OPT_RETRY_TIMEOUT
- Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT

In PHP I will do like so:

```
$cache = new Memcached();
$cache->addServer('serv01', 11211);
$cache->addServer('serv02', 11211);
$cache->addServer('serv03', 11211);
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_HASH, Memcached::HASH_MD5);
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION, Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT);
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 150);
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_RETRY_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

But so far I have not found any documentation or examples of how to set those variables when they are use by the session_handler.

Comment: Here's an out of the box implementation using PHP and memcached. http://kvz.io/blog/2008/06/22/enhance-php-session-management/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking trough the source code of both PECL extension and libmemcached itself I finally found my answer in the comment of the blog of the author of the memcached extension.

http://zmievski.org/2009/01/new-memcached-extension

I quote in case his blog disappeared some day:

> **Andrei said:** @Ash, the session save path syntax is not quite the same as the other memcache extension. Try:
>
> session.save_path="127.0.0.1:11211"
>
> **Ash Searle said:** Is there any documentation for the syntax – i.e. does it handle multiple servers and optional parameters like the earlier memcache implementations?
>   (e.g. save_path="127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15")
>
> **Andrei said:** @Ash, no, it’s not that advanced. For now, the syntax is the default one that libmemcached parser supports: basically, a comma-separated list of hostname:port entries, where :port is optional.

OR

> **Rich Choy said:** Is there a reference on the Web that explains each connection parameter that appears after host:port? For example what exactly does “timeout=1″ mean?
>
> **Andrei said:** @Rich, which extension are you using? :) Mine doesn’t support those extra parameters, you must be talking about pecl/memcache one.

AND

> **Frank Orson said:** 1) Does pecl/memcached support UDP on the client? I could not find any info about this. I know that pecl/memcache 3.0.4 supports it.
>
> 2) Does pecl/memcached have failover support in the client?
>
> **Andrei said:** Frank, I’m working on next version (2.0) of the memcached extension. It’ll have UDP support and replication (failover).

If you check the source code of version 2 you can see for example that you can append in the save_path string "PERSISTENT=" and "--SERVER" ((which I don't know how it would be used)

Answer (score 3):

You need to write your own session handler and wrap Memcache(d) methods around it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: If I have no other answers I will accept yours but I really would like to avoid writing my own session handler.

Comment: There is no other way around this.